# NCrunch integration with Typemock failing to run tests

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, typemock, ncrunch

I am getting the following exception from NCrunch when tests are being run.

```
*** Failures ***

Execute
TypeMock.TypeMockException: 
*** Typemock Isolator is currently disabled. Enable using the following:

 * Within Visual Studio: 
   - Use Typemock Smart Runner  
   - For other runners, Choose Typemock Menu and click "Integrate with Other Runners"

 * To run Typemock Isolator as part of an automated process you can:
    - run tests via TMockRunner.exe command line tool
    - use 'TypeMockStart' tasks for MSBuild or NAnt

For more information consult the documentation (see 'Running Unit Tests in an Automated Build')
HResult: -2146233088
   at TypeMock.InterceptorsWrapper.VerifyInterceptorsIsLoaded()
   at _I2KaEbJqCiZdAXHCaew5L4YgGK2_._YVpKHl6s8x54awChyHFFGG1W9p_._M9wuZsfNQUSOigKL83XBnloMATg_()
   at TypeMock.MockManager.Init(Boolean collectAllCalls)
   at _gpWkmvHy51MsHfP5XcTmisQFOGh_._w05d89eUlRCsAnXfWIN6HIvOW7P_._LZu54JRvjOVy0mycnVTOacyFHBR_[?](Members , Constructor , Constructor , Type , Object[] )
   at _gpWkmvHy51MsHfP5XcTmisQFOGh_._w05d89eUlRCsAnXfWIN6HIvOW7P_.Instance[T](Members behavior, ConstructorWillBe constructorBehavior, BaseConstructorWillBe baseConstructorBehavior)
   at NOES.Business.Control.Rollformers.RollformerStateIdleTest.SendNextBagTest() in C:\Users\Frank Adcock\Documents\noes_3\src\NOESTest\Business\Control\Rollformers\RollformerStateIdleTest.cs:line 18
```

Version Details

- VS2015 14.0.25420.01 Update 3
- Typemock 8.5.0.2
- Test Frameworks Galio/MbUnit or Nunit 3.43

From what I can read of the documentation Typemock is supposed to be automatically picked up by NCrunch, but this does not appear to be happening.

Any assistance welcomed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We fixed this issue and you gonna see it in our next release.
As a workaround for now:

- Find a "knownRunners.dat" in the Typemock Examples folder
- Add 2 lines to it: "nCrunch.EngineHost462.x64", "nCrunch.EngineHost462.x86"

See [here](https://www.typemock.com/docs?book=Isolator&page=Documentation%2FHtmlDocs%2FExtendConfiguration.htm) a full info

Tell me if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer, I work in Typemock.

First of all, have you enabled "Integrate with Other Runners" in Typemock VS menu and "Enable Mocking integration" and "Enable Auto Linking" in Typemock->Options->Mocking Integration?

Which version of NCrunch you use?